# NoSuchProviderException when encrypting string with 3DES

Tags: java, android, encryption, 3des

I am new to Java. I followed this [tutorial](http://ttux.net/post/3des-java-encrypter-des-java-encryption/) about Encryption and Decryption using 3DES algorithm.

I have implemented like this:

1. Created a class and placed the 3DES code provided in the above link.
2. Called the encrypt method in the above link as below:

   ```
   String encryptedPassword = Encrypter.encrypt(edtText.getText().toString());
   ```

I am getting the exception in logcat as below:

```
 05-02 15:19:10.804: W/System.err(4445): java.security.NoSuchProviderException: Provider not available: SunJCE
    05-02 15:19:10.820: W/System.err(4445):     at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:209)
    05-02 15:19:10.820: W/System.err(4445):     at com.example.utilities.Encrypter.encrypt(Encrypter.java:46)
    05-02 15:19:10.820: W/System.err(4445):     at com.example.screens.RegisterScreen.onClick(RegisterScreen.java:152)
    05-02 15:19:10.820: W/System.err(4445):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    05-02 15:19:10.820: W/System.err(4445):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    05-02 15:19:10.828: W/System.err(4445):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    05-02 15:19:10.828: W/System.err(4445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-02 15:19:10.828: W/System.err(4445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    05-02 15:19:10.828: W/System.err(4445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    05-02 15:19:10.835: W/System.err(4445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-02 15:19:10.835: W/System.err(4445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    05-02 15:19:10.835: W/System.err(4445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    05-02 15:19:10.835: W/System.err(4445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    05-02 15:19:10.835: W/System.err(4445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me. How to solve this....

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are specifying the SunJCE provider. That doesn't make any sense even where it would work, such as in Oracle's java runtime. Of course that provider doesn't exist on Android. Use the default provider unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @GregS Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @GregS can u please post a solution for this?

Comment: @DuncanJones can u please help me....

Comment: @user2326860 Alter your code and remove anywhere where it explicitly states `"SunJCE"`. For example, change `("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE");` to `("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was being lazy. The line

```
Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE");
```

shows that you are specifying a particular provider. Normally you would want a very good reason for doing this, for example you might be required to use a FIPS-compliant provider. The SunJCE provider does not exist on Android. Just use the default provider, which you get simply by leaving out that argument. So try:

```
Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Similarly, change

```
Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE");
```

to

```
Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```